Copy Formulas in Cell A13 Through K13
I have a file that has a power query in it.  The query begins in Column row 13 column M and brings in a variable number of rows each month. In cell A13 through K13, I have a set of formulas that I would like to drag or copy down to the last row that is brought in by Power query in Column M each time.  How would I do this?


Hint: how to find the last used cell.

The simplest solution would be to integrate the formulas into the Power Query.  The second simplest solution would be to have the formulas in the columns after last column of the Power query (Excel will handle extending the formulas automatically).

I don't think I was being clear.  I have excel formulas in cells A13 through K13.  These formulas are (e.g., =IF(K13="-","-",ROW()). Is there a way to use VBA to copy these formulas down to the last row using autofill or something similar using VBA?

Update Formulas Corresponding to Rows of an Excel Table (ListObject)

The formula used in this example is
=COLUMN()*Table1[@Numbers]





Imagine there are formulas only in A2:K2. PowerQuery has produced 10 data rows in the table. After running UdateFormulas, the formulas are copied down.
If PowerQuery now produces 5 data rows in the table, running UpdateFormulas will clear all formulas except the ones in the first row and copy them down 5 rows.

Sub UpdateFormulas()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim lo As ListObject: Set lo = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    If lo.ListRows.Count < 2 Then Exit Sub ' first row has already formulas
    
    ' Copy formulas and formats.
    With lo.DataBodyRange.EntireRow.Columns("A:K")
        .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row).Offset(1).Clear ' keep first row
        .Rows(1).Copy .Cells
    End With

'    ' Copy only formulas (more efficient).
'    With lo.DataBodyRange.EntireRow.Columns("A:K")
'        .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row).Offset(1).ClearContents ' keep first row
'        .Formula = .Rows(1).Formula ' copy as many as rows in table
'    End With

End Sub

